# Orthogonal complement of a subspace of $C[-1,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider $C[1,1]$ equipped with the scalar product induced from $L^{2}[-1,1]$, i.e. $<f,g>$ = $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\overline{g(x)} dx$. Compute the orthogonal complement of the following subspaces of $C[-1,1]$:

$M_{1} = \{f \in C[-1,1] : f(x) = 0$ for $x\le 0$$\}$

$M_{2} = \{f \in C[-1,1] : f(0) = 0\}$

For the first one I see now (after Olof's comment) that the complement would be $\{g \in C[-1,1] : g(x) = 0$ for $x \gt 0\}$

For the second one I am really not sure how to proceed. Since the interval is symmetric my initial thought was  to find a $g$ that turns an arbitrary $f$ $\in$ $M_{2}$ into an odd function but I don't think such a $g$ exists.

Comment: Isn't any function $g$ with $g(x) = 0$ for $x\geq 0$ in $M_1^\perp$?

Comment: Oh yes of course thats silly of me. The second one is the one im having trouble with

Comment: So the orthogonal complement of $M_{1}$ is just the functions $g$ with $g(x)=0$ for $x\gt0$ right?

Comment: @duelspace It's not $x>0$, it's $x \ge 0$, as Olof R said in his comment. 
Yes, that's the orthogonal complement of $M_1$, but you'll have to prove it. Hint: If a continuous function $g$ is not $0$ at a point $x$, then there is a whole neighborhood of $x$ where it's not $0$.

Comment: For the second one, see here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046047/finding-the-orthogonal-complement-to-a-subspace?rq=1

Comment: @jjagmath Ah I see thank you!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I will take a look thank you

Comment: @duelspace You are welcome!